# Add d3.js table to existing html

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am trying to add this example code (pure js table):

http://jsfiddle.net/christopheviau/v6VMf/

to an existing html page which has other d3.js elements above. I cannot seem to modify the table code properly to select the correct divs and get the table to appear.

My existing css and html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- D3.js -->
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <style>
        body {
            font-size: 10px;
            font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 400;
            fill: #8C8C8C;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #wrapper {
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            width:1000px;
        }

        .title {
            font-size: 28px;
            fill: #4F4F4F;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-anchor: start;
            left: 18px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .subtitle {
            font-size: 14px;
            fill: #AAAAAA;
            font-weight: 300;
            text-anchor: start;
            left: 18px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .progress, .label {
            margin: 20px;
            width: 200px;
            height: 100px;
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .radial-progress { 
          &__text {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-size: 2rem;
            font-weight: bold;
          }  
        }

        .clear { clear: both }

        .label {
          font-size: 18px;
          text-align: center;
          margin: 0 19px;
          height: 0px;
        }

        .sideHeader {
          height: 20px;
          width: 140px;
          float: left;
        }

        .sideLabel1 {
          font-size: 18px;
          float: left;
          align-items: center;
          display: inline-flex;
          height: 200px;
          width: 135px;
          margin: 0px 20;
        }

    </style>
</head> 

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="provider_longname" class="title"></div>
    <div id="current_as_of" class="subtitle"></div>
    <div id="contribution" class="subtitle"></div>
    <div id="data_transfer" class="subtitle"></div>
    <div id="madis_category" class="subtitle"></div>
    <div class="sideHeader"></div>
    <div class="label">Last 24 hours</div>
    <div class="label">Last 7 days</div>
    <div class="label">Last 30 days</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="sideLabel1">Station Reports:</div>

    <div
      data-track-width="15" 
      data-track-colour="555555" 
      data-fill-colour="228B22" 
      data-text-colour="383838" 
      data-stroke-colour="FFFFFF" 
      data-stroke-spacing="1"
      id="radial1"
      class="progress">
    </div>

    <div
      data-track-width="15" 
      data-track-colour="555555" 
      data-fill-colour="228B22" 
      data-text-colour="383838" 
      data-stroke-colour="FFFFFF" 
      data-stroke-spacing="1"
      id="radial2"
      class="progress"> 
    </div>

    <div
      data-track-width="15" 
      data-track-colour="555555" 
      data-fill-colour="228B22" 
      data-text-colour="383838" 
      data-stroke-colour="FFFFFF" 
      data-stroke-spacing="1"
      id="radial3"
      class="progress"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, my html contains a script tag with additional code for data vars and d3.js elements. What modifications do I need to make to the jsfiddle code to get this table to append to my existing html page?

Answer (score 0):

Change the root node to a child node in your document:

```
d3.select('body')
    .datum(dataset)
    .call(table);
```

to:

```
d3.select('#elementId')
    .datum(dataset)
    .call(table);
```

```
<div id="elementId"></div>
```

Comment: I added a `<div id="table1"></div>` inside my wrapper div. And then use `d3.select('#table1')`. However, I get a console error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (index.html:482)`. The traceback line is `.style({fill:'#eee', stroke:'silver'});`.

Comment: As of d3 v4 you can no longer pass objects to the style attribute in the base d3 package. You need to add the d3-multi-select package to be able to do this.